# How to avoid repeated OK/ALARM transitions for CloudWatch alarms?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

### How to reproduce

1. Create a Lambda function `myFunction` which succeeds:

   ```
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       return
   ```
2. Test the function at 10:55
3. Go to CloudWatch → Metrics → Lambda → `myFunction` Errors
4. Click "Create Alarm"
5. Select ">", a **period of 5 minutes**, and remove the default notification action, resulting in a threshold of "Errors > 0 for 5 minutes"
6. Save at 10:58
7. Change the function to fail:

   ```
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       raise Exception()
   ```
8. Test `myFunction` at 10:59, resulting in an error count of 1 in the CloudWatch log for the function at that time

### What happens in the alarm history after 10:59

1. State transition to "alarm" at 10:59
2. State transition to "insufficient data" at **11:15**

### What I expect to happen

1. State transition to "alarm" at 10:59
2. State transition to "insufficient data" at **11:04**

### Analysis

The state transition to "insufficient data" doesn't happen at 11:04. There's a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277644/96588) saying it should happen at 11:09 (two periods), but instead it happens after more than three. Is the period until "insufficient data" even more arbitrary than expected?